# How to uninstall games?

Tags: 8.1

After 8.1 update, uninstall is not available in the games app anymore. How can I uninstall unwanted games now?

After tapping, the menu only has rate or review now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all the games are in your app list now, you can uninstall from there. Tap and hold on the game you wish to uninstall and there is an option there.

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall games from the app list, just like any other app. Simply tap and hold and you'll get the uninstall option.

Games and apps can also be uninstalled from the Storage Sense app. Open Storage Sense, tap on the bar representing your phone (or SD card), tap on "apps+games", then tap on the game you wish to uninstall and the option will be on the next screen.